# Help understand Z value of CameraToWorldPoint

Tags: unity

I do not understand what this CameraToWorldPoint function is used for, what is the use case of this function:

1.From my understanding, my cursor is sitting on the near clipping plane, so I am actually clicking all the points on the near clipping plane, the near clipping plane represents my screen, am I right?

2.When I use this function to convert B point to world point, I am getting the point C position, is that true?

3.Is part A->C represent the Z value, or part B->C is the Z value?

4.Then finally, is this function useless? Because I get a world position in the predefined Z position, and I do not even know what Z value should be in the first place, I can randomly assign a pointless Z value, so what is use case for this function, I know raycast can do anything I want, but when to use this function?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z value of `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` is the depth from the camera where you want the point to be placed.

This function is something we call an "un-projection". We're taking a projected point in 2D space, and reversing the camera's projection to go into 3D space. The problem is that projections destroy information. When say the player clicks pick a point on the screen, we only have two dimensions worth of information about which position in the world they meant, but we need three dimensions worth to get a 3D point.

So that third piece of information needs to be added by us, the developers, in a way that's consistent with the feature we're trying to implement - since there's no one universal way to deduce it from a 2D point that will work for every feature we might imagine.

> Am I clicking all the points on the near clipping plane? Does the near clipping plane represent my screen?

Well, that's one way you can think of it. But we could just as easily say that you're clicking points on the far clipping plane.

Take a particular position on your near plane. Draw a ray from the camera position through that point, and keep extending it to or even past the far plane. Every point on that ray maps to the same position on the screen, just at different depths (z values).

This depth corresponds to how far you've travelled "forward" along the camera's viewing direction, from the position of the camera itself.

```
float depth = Vector3.Dot(
               camera.transform.forward,
               worldPoint - camera.position
              );
```

Or equivalently:

```
float depth = camera.transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldPoint).z;
```

That's similar to the A-C distance in your diagram. But just note we're measuring this distance along the camera's forward axis, not along the ray joining the camera to the point of interest.

[image: Diagram showing z depth]

Each different depth or z value defines a plane slicing through your scene, perpendicular to the camera's forward axis. (If we measured along the ray instead, each depth value would define a spherical shell rather than a flat plane)

The near clipping plane is at `depth = camera.nearClipPlane`, and the far clipping plane is at `depth = camera.farClipPlane`, intuitively enough.

> Is this function useless?

No. But it might not be the function that solves your present problem.

It sounds like you might be trying to solve a picking problem, where the player clicks on the screen, and you want to know the closest object or surface under the clicked screen point. In this case, we have no information in the input about what depth the player meant, but we can infer it from our scene geometry. For that problem, you'd use `Camera.ScreenToWorldRay` to get the whole ray of potential positions we described before, then do a physics raycast along this ray to find where it intersects a pickable object the player can see.

`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` is useful for cases where you already know the depth you want. Say the player already clicked a sphere, and now wants to drag it around the scene. We could set up our dragging mechanic so that it keeps the object at its original depth from the camera, so the player is dragging it along a plane perpendicular to their view, never bringing it closer or further away. To do that, we'd store the depth of the picked object in a member variable when the player first clicks on it, then on subsequent frames use it as our z value to unproject the latest cursor position to a point on that plane to move the object to.

We'll also use this if we want to position something exactly at the near or far planes, by passing the values of those camera parameters as z.

Or we might use it to position worldspace UI like health bars, name labels, or AR elements a fixed screen distance above an object, using that object's depth from the camera as our z so the UI sits in the same plane.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it is cleared something for me, but I still have a few point don not understand, the cursor on my screen, you said it is on the far plane, but when I am moving my cursor, before the ScreenToWorldPoint, without imagine there is is ray to the far end, why it could be on the far plane, it has to be a certain plane on where the cursor is moving

Comment: I did not say it was on the far plane. I said we can think of it as being on the far plane, and that is every bit as valid as it being on the near plane. Because "it has to be a certain plane on where the cursor is moving" is absolutely false. There is no such requirement. The cursor is moving on the screen in pixel units, not in the world at all. We can choose to associate those pixel positions with particular planes, but that's a free choice: we can pick absolutely any plane we want to. So there's nothing special about the near or far planes here. They have nothing to do with the cursor.

Comment: This idea totally ruined my whole understanding of cursor plane and world plane, thanks a lot I need to do a few trials to justify this is right and reconstruct my understanding